# Is it possible to animate textures scale?

Tags: texturing

Is it possible to animate texture scale on an object?
I have created a node to scale my texture for my object. 
I stretched the object, and to avoid stretching of the texture, I created a node. Now I try to keyframe the Y scale of the texture, without success. 
I clicked i and choose locrotscale, and that didn't do the job. 
What am i missing here? If I can animate the scale of a texture on an object, how do I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a mapping node to control your texture node. The scale values can then be animated by adding keyframes.

[image]

for blender internal the same principle applies:

[image]

Comment: cegaton, the original poster did not specify cycles in the question. is there a possible way to animate the scale of the textures with Blender's internal rendering engine, or would one have to animate the texture's underlying geometry?

Comment: usually i click "i" for locrot, but you seem to have another kind of keyframe insert menu . that does not look like the "i " for locrot that i use.  so i am still stuck here, i cannot find that menu on my laptop.  the "i" for locrot is the only way i know to use for animation.  does it mean this task can not be done in the "i" for loc rot menu ?

Comment: To animate anything in blender your can hover over the property you want to change and right click to bring the context menu and select add keyframe, but pressing **i** should work as well.

Comment: yes i have pressed "i" but my context menu that pops up looks a lot different than your context pop up from your key frame menu.  and here in my pop-up menu is a list of choices of many selections,  like: locrot , etc .  i searched in edit menus to see if i could find the same popup context menu from you video , but no luck . how exactly do you open that key frame pop up that you show in your video. i have a trackpad  that i can use for a right click , so i should be able to do that. what do you choose from the context menu when you press "i"  ?  that would probably all clear for me :) thanks

Comment: As said: move the cursor to **hover over** the value slider you want to change and press the right mouse boutton. The options you are talking about only apply when moving objects on the 3D viewport. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ijUoP.gif

Comment: Yes found it , perfect and thanks a lot :) this gonna be fun now :) love Blender :)